# passing javascript throught textarea inside a form

Tags: javascript, php, forms, textarea

I would like to ask a question. 
Is there a way to pass jquery script over textarea and being accepted by php with $_POST function?
just like w3schools did, I've tried but the jquery script are missing and I don't know why..
Please somebody help me. Thank you!

```
<form action="showHTML.php" method="post" >
<textarea name="html" id="hello">
<script src="lib/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("body").css({backgroundColor:"red"});
});
</script>
</textarea>
<form>
```

And this is my php file that i used to grab the content from the $_POST

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['html'])  and  !empty($_POST['html'])){
  $data = htmlentities($_POST['html']);
}else{
  echo '<p>Edit the HTML to the right.</p>';
}

echo html_entity_decode($data);
?>
```

Comment: Whatever the problem is, it isn't exposed by that code.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="lib/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="showHTML.php" method="post" >
<textarea name="html" id="hello">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("body").css({backgroundColor:"red"});
  });
</textarea>
<form>﻿
```

Now get the script as text from `showHTML.php` and process it from there. I guess you can't put script tag inside text area like what you have done.

Comment: so do you have any suggestion how to achieve that? is there any other way to get script tag? because I'm doing some research about personal code editor.

Comment: Please provide more info on what you want to pass using `post` and what you are going to do with it in `php`

Comment: I've already updated the question above, and I added the php file there. thank you

Answer (score 0):

your code should look like this: close your **form tag** and add a button to submit.

```
 <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("body").css({backgroundColor:"red"});
});
</script>
 <form action="showHTML.php" method="post" >
<textarea name="html" id="hello">
</textarea>
<input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

----^

**php:**

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['html'])  and  !empty($_POST['html'])){
  $data = htmlentities($_POST['html']);
}else{
  echo '<p>Edit the HTML to the right.</p>';
}

echo html_entity_decode($data);
?>
```